# How to solve congruence equations such as $ a-x^2 \equiv 0\bmod{b} $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I take any 2 natural numbers: $a$ and $b$, such that $a \gt b$

How to solve this type of congruence equation to find $x$?:
$$
a-x^2 \equiv 0\bmod{b}
$$

Give me an example.

What properties of modular arithmetic can I use?

Comment: [Quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue).

Comment: it's $x^2\equiv a\bmod b$

Answer (score 1):

So, basically you are looking for [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue). There is no concrete way you can solve your equation for all such $a$ and $b$. But it is helpful to know the [Legendre symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreSymbol.html) when you deal with such type of equations.

I can provide one example of how you can approach (simple) problem: Solve equation $15-x^2 \equiv 0 \ (mod \ 7)$. Solution: $15-x^2 \equiv 0 \ (mod \ 3) \implies x^2 \equiv 15 \ (mod \ 7) \implies x^2 \equiv15-7\cdot2 \ (mod \ 7) \implies x^2 \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 7) \implies x^2-1 \equiv 0 \ (mod \ 7) \implies 3|(x-1)(x+1) \implies x \equiv\pm1 \ (mod \ 7)$.

You can post your exact problem, it will make it easier to understand.

Comment: I suspected it could get complicated. But when you say "There is no concrete way you can solve your equation for all such a and b", did it mean that some of these equations can be solved? If so, can I post a new question with the specific problem?

Comment: @PedroUrday Yes, it would be much better if you give us specific numbers so we can wrap up the properties. There is a way to point out *how many* $a$ and $b$ is possible, but it is just too broad to show which one in the residues are they.